# Telerik for MAUI - how to fix RadDataGrid not filling the available grid space?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, telerik, maui, telerik-grid

I'm having this UI Issue with the RadDataGrid feature of Telerik.

[image]

The above Image demonstrates my issue. As you can see on the right hand side there is white space representing the available space in the grid(the darker grey being the page).

Things I have attempted to fix the issue that do not work.

Adding the following properties to the  `<telerik:RadDataGrid>` tag

```
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
```

My code for the grid is shown below also.

```
<Grid Margin="30" >
        <!-- other controls or elements can be added here -->
        
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <telerik:RadDataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="dataGrid"
                     ShowGroupFooters="False"
                     CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     UserGroupMode="Disabled"                       
                     GridLinesVisibility="Both">
</Grid>
```

If required, here is an example of how I am defining one of my columns.

```
                <telerik:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Description" HeaderText="Description"  SizeMode="Auto" >
                    
                    <telerik:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <telerik:DataGridColumnHeaderStyle BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Blue}"
                                               TextColor="White"
                                               BorderColor="LightGray"
                                               BorderThickness="2" 
                                               TextFontSize="10"/>
                    </telerik:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <telerik:DataGridTextColumn.CellContentStyle>
                        <telerik:DataGridTextCellStyle                                        
                                        FontSize="10"                                      
                                         />
                    </telerik:DataGridTextColumn.CellContentStyle>

                </telerik:DataGridTextColumn>
```

What I want to achieve is for this DataGrid to adjust itself depending on the screen/grid size, as this issue doesn't occur if the window size is smaller as the grid does not need to expand.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/maui/controls/datagrid/columns/width

Doc says column SizeMode Auto takes max needed by any row in that column. That’s what you are seeing.

Instead, set each column’s `SizeMode="Stretch"`.

That will allocate extra space, in proportion to each column’s desired size.